# Linking to an exact subset of apps on the android market

Tags: google-play, android

Is there a way that I could link from inside my app to the android market, but only to a specific list of apps. Something like this using wildcards would be ideal (but it does not work) :

```
market://search?q=pname:com.somepackage.*
```

So. I want list when opened in Android Market app after clicking on that link to contain only my apps, but not all of my apps, only just exact subset. Is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have done it in the following way. Firstly, when you search for an app on the market it looks like that Google is doing full text search with the given query through the apps descriptions. I allready had this in my apps descriptions :

```
tags : tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5...
```

Now I have just added **someReallyUniqueTag** to all of my apps tags that I want to show, so I make a workaround to showing just a subset of my apps to users with a market query. Query looks like this :

```
"market://search?q=pub:yourRealPublisherName someReallyUniqueTag"
```

It works instantly after adding new app to the market with such a tag in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link from the Android Docs. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#PerformingSearch

You could do something like: market://search?q=pub:Your Publisher Name and have it only return results that match your pub name.

Comment: That will show a list of ALL my apps. I want a way to show just a subset of my apps.